# Android Studio preview - set an adapter to a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio

Is it possible to set up an `Adapter` to a `RecyclerView` on the layout `xml` file so that it renders it design-time?  Similar to the way it uses `tools:context=my.package.MyFragment` to render other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I know, you can't really add your own adapter, but is possible to use the decent default preview adapter, specifying your layout item.

Something like that:

```
<FrameLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        tools:listitem="@layout/your_item_layout"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```